# Definition of computability of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, computability

What exactly does it mean to say that a real number $x$ is computable?  I can think of two reasonable definitions but I am not sure whether or not they are equivalent:

1) There is an algorithm which given $n$ outputs the $n^{\text{th}}$ bit of the binary representation of $x$.

2) There is an algorithm which given $n$ outputs a rational number $q$ with $\vert{q-x}\vert \le \frac{1}{n}$.

The troublesome case is the following: Let $z$ be the reciprocal of the length of the shortest proof of falsehood in ZFC if ZFC is inconsistent, else $0$ if ZFC is consistent, and let $x = 1 - z$.  So either $x=1$ or $x = 0.1111...0...$.  Seemingly the latter definition is satisfied but not the former.  In the latter case, the program can spend some time hunting for a contradiction in ZFC and then output a sufficiently precise approximation whether or not a contradiction is found.  In the former case, we cannot even determine the first bit, unless ZFC is actually inconsistent.  Is this reasoning that the definitions are not equivalent correct?  If so, what definition (perhaps neither) is standard, and how can the argument be stated more clearly?  If the definitions are in fact equivalent, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number you describe is a rational. Thus it is certainly computable, by either of your definitions. The fact that we don't know *which* computation outputs approximations to $x$ is not relevant.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, so my example is invalid.  I expect I will be able to figure out what is wrong with my argument on that basis.  Are the definitions equivalent then?

Comment: I think so, for essentially the same reason. I haven't fully checked the details.

Comment: The definitions are actually equivalent, because either a number has a terminating binary expansion (in which case the algorithm consists of a finite number of "$1$" cases and "$0$ otherwise") or not (in which case we can try better and better rational approximations until we get one that decides the $n$'th bit).  The reason that (1) is preferred is that it allows effective algorithms for functions.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I think I get it now -- when $x$ is rational, it is computable, and when $x$ is not rational, it has a non-terminating binary expansion, so in that case algorithm (1) can be implemented by making calls to algorithm (2).

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning is not correct.  If ZFC is consistent, there is an algorithm that outputs $x$, namely "output $1$".  It's just that we don't happen to know that this algorithm is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers address your particular example, but *not* the equivalence of the two representations.

The base-2 representation of real numbers and the Cauchy representation (your second representation) do indeed define the same set of computable numbers.

*However*, the functions computable on these representations differ (multiplication by 3 is not computable in the base-2 representation -- Turing originally noted this for base-10).